# Duplicate content when paginating through Elasticsearch results

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have 3 data nodes, 2 master nodes and imported a lot of text content. I wrote some queries to get search data but getting paginated search results is returning some duplicate results from previous page. (few page 1 results show up on page 2, page 2 results are duplicated on page 3, so on and so forth).

Here is my NEST query, I am not sure what to change to get only unique results as I go through new pages.

```
                mediaResponse = elastic.Search<Articles>(s => s
                                                           .Explain(true)
                                                           .Pretty(true)
                                                           .Human(true)
                                                           .Index(mediaIndexName)
                                                           .Type(mediaTypeName)
                                                           .From(pageNumber)
                                                           .Size(numResults)
                                                           .Query(q => q
                                                                        .Match(m => m
                                                                                     .Field(new Field("content", null)).Query(queryTxt)
                                                                              )
                                                                 )
            );
```

Any ideas on how to get this work properly?

Comment: Try to use sorted query instead: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/sort-usage.html#_nested_sort_usage

Comment: Sounds like you may have documents with equal scores. As @SouXin suggests, look at adding sorting: first by `_score` descending, then by another unique field e.g. `_id`

Comment: @RussCam Items are coming from different shards. I don't know how to search and avoid data from multiple shards.

Comment: I don't think the number of shards makes a difference here. Is the data static, or is new data being indexed whilst searching? If the latter, then that can affect pagination results

Comment: @RussCam Data is being added but about 10 items a day so not much indexing going on there.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments it's possible that diffent shards rank the same document differently, thus return it on different pages. Try adding the [Preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-preference) parameter to ensure consistency for a given result set with multiple pages.